# Display selected part of a webpage in an iframe

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have to display a part of an external webpage in my iframe. My approach to this is 
1 – Open the actual page in the iframe, then position the frame so that the proper content is showing, hiding the overflow.
2 – Use an ajax request to scrape the content from the page, pulling out just the text and displaying it in my own iframe.
It is getting trickier to accomplish. Is there any easy solution? Please help....

Answer (score -1):

Unless you can use fragment urls, Ajax is the way to go.

Comment: If my answer was correct, please mark it as such. (And preferably "undo" the downvote)